# jQuery clone().html() adds separate end tag on xhtml element

Tags: jquery, clone

Calling `clone().html()` on a XHTML element seems to reconstruct the element and add a separate closing tag. Is there a way to avoid this?

```js
var clone = $("#test").clone().html();
$("#test").text(clone);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id="test">
  <ix:tuple name="se-ar-base:UttalandenTuple" tupleID="UttalandenTuple1" />
</span>
<span id="test2"></span>
```

Comment: It's not jQuery doing this, but the browser renderer. If you remove the jQuery code and inspect the DOM, you'll see that the closing `</ix:tuple>` element has been added for you. It's due to the fact that this is not valid HTML (or even XHTML, which is very outdated now), and the browser is trying to fix your mistake for you. If you want to avoid this, encode the string first - although presumably this is intended to be part of a server-side templating library which you are mistakenly outputting to the client.

Comment: If you really want to keep the self-closing tag, you could be really dirty and add `.replace(/>\s*<\/ix:tuple>/,'/>')` to the end of your `.clone().html()`

Comment: Alright I see, hmm well have to look over the code then. Thanks!